# LINQ - to Entities doesn't recognize the method system.string ToString() exception

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've got the above ring exception in my code. What I try is to use where clause with a list variable and that's why I use Contains method but I keep getting the error and I can't understand what I do wrong

```
List<string> TouristID = (List<string>)Session["TouristID"];
    List<Tourist> customerInterests = (from tourist in db2.Tourist
                             where (TouristID.Contains(tourist.Tourist_ID.ToString()))
                             select tourist).ToList();

foreach (var customer in customerInterests)
{
    String strName_kir = customer.Name_kir;
    String Lastname_kir = customer.Midname_kir;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Make your `List<string>` a `List<int>` and then drop the `.ToString()` call and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I already did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToString()` method is not evaluated by LinQ to Entities, because it cannot be translated to SQL.

Try to change the type of your list to the destination type or parse them into a new List.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot use `.ToString()` inside a LinqToSql expression because it will try to translate it to SQL

Comment: thanks! I'm really sleepy and I even can't see what I'm writing. ThANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `ToString` or any other methods that cannot be translated to SQL.

You should be able to do the following:

```
List<string> TouristID = (List<string>)Session["TouristID"];

//Get them as integers
var touristIds = TouristID.Select(x => int.Parse(x));

List<Tourist> customerInterests = (from tourist in db2.Tourist
                         where (touristIds.Contains(tourist.Tourist_ID))
                         select tourist).ToList();
```